# Is there a way to simulate raspbian without using qemu?

Tags: raspbian

I want to simulate raspbian on ubuntu. I can successful install rasbian according to this: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=37386 and some search. I want to install web server in raspbain but i can't access nginx server outside qemu so i wonder is there is another way to simulate raspbian on ubuntu ?

Comment: It seems that your problem is that you can't access server hosted by qemu OS from... host OS? Outside world? Why don't you try to solve that instead of throwing it all away and looking for another solution?

Comment: because i think qemu doesn't allow host os access qemu server and my boss say there is a way to install raspbian directly in vmware. i has perform some search but doesn't find any clue so i came here to ask.

Comment: @ThanhTranVan QEMU is the best known method to run Raspbian without hardware. Recent patches give ability to boot Raspbian without big problems. You can read about it [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=873834#p873834) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34570571/587395). I agree with @MirosławZalewski advice. You should focus on solving issue. Using QEMU version that I point to, enabling networking and `-redir` option should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

*Advice here is semi-accurate but may not be completely precise; I'm just a teenager who likes Raspberry Pi*

Virtualisation ≠ emulation.

There are two main types of processor in use: x86 / x86-64 and ARM. x86 is built for performance and is normally used on PCs; ARM is built lightweight for cheapness, low power consumption and efficiency and is normally used in smartphones. They both use different instruction sets so cannot run each others' binaries and applications.

A good quote from amoeba on Reddit (https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/1ea5r2/eli5_why_are_x86_programs_not_compatible_with_arm/):

> Running x86 [operating systems] on Arm [and vice versa] is like trying to put diesel in a gas car - they're just not made to run it. Even if you're driving a car that's available in both forms, it won't work. The gear shift and brake pedals might be in the same spot but the engine won't run the same stuff.

Raspbian is made to run on a Raspberry Pi which uses an ARM processor - so it can't run in its original form on a standard PC (x86/x86-64). VMWare (suggested) uses virtualisation; this is a method of using the PC's CPU to split the computer into several virtual servers (all using the PC's CPU) which operate like individual computers. This can be used to, say, simulate Windows on a Mac, but it only works if the operating system being simulated is compatible with the CPU of the computer - i.e. Raspbian on ARM system cannot be simulated with virtualisation on an x86/x86-64 system. A workaround is to emulate an ARM system right down to the CPU- i.e. qemu. However, since you are simulating a CPU within a computer, it will be much slower and there will be more limitations on it.

What your boss might be referring to is virtualisation of versions of Linux that look similar to Raspbian but which are compatible with x86 - e.g. Debian or Puppy Linux.

I don't use qemu myself, but after a bit of research I found what could be a solution to access nginx server outside qemu (it probably won't work but you should give it a try):
If your nginx server is running on port 80:

- Launch qemu with the flag `-redir tcp:8080::80` (e.g. `qemu -redir tcp:8080::80`)
- Access server through http://localhost:8080